# Trying to Load data using Django loaddata but its throwing below error.py is not a known serialization format

Tags: django, loaddata

When im trying to load data in Django it is throwing out above error.

python manage.py loaddata path_of_file.py

Comment: Well, indeed, Python files are not supported as an argument to loaddata. What exactly is in that file?

Answer (score 2):

The loaddata command only accepts serialized files (such as json) or compressed files (such as zip).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture